# Alternative to meeting workspace in 2010

Tags: meeting-workspace

How to create a meeting workspace in sharepoint 2010 without using the default template??in our organization they have removed the meeting workspace template from 2010 as they don't want to lose any data while migrating to 2013.
Can someone help in creating meeting workspace??
I have tried numerous ways and was not able to find a solution exactly similar to the original meeting workspace in 2010

Comment: Can you please clarify if you need the functionality for 2010 or 2013, your question does not make that clear

Comment: I need solution for SharePoint 2010

Comment: Can anyone please help me out??

Answer (score 1):

Dunno know if you are migrated to SP2013 by now or not? But if you are then this could be your solution.

[The alternative for Meeting Workspaces in SharePoint 2013](http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/the-alternative-for-meeting-workspaces-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: If you look into the link then you will be assured that this is the correct workflow for the query, only if he has upgraded to SP2013. I looked everywhere not missed even a single blog, discussion etc but didnt get better than that. So when you get time then please go through that blog.

Answer (score 1):

The Meeting templates still exist in SharePoint 2013, they are just hidden. They can be enabled again.

You might find this links useful

http://www.sharepointsapiens.com/blog/workspace-templates-missing/

This blog below shows you how to display hidden templates in SharePoint 2013

https://blog.zubairalexander.com/how-to-display-hidden-templates-in-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an alternative, but this is what I'm trialing for one departments's meeting site.

I created a new page on the site and called it Meetings.  I made them decide on the libraries, etc they would want to see for each meeting and then created those libraries.  In each library, I added a column for 'Meeting Date'.  They have to fill that in for every document they upload.

On the main page, I changed the library web parts to group by Meeting Date, and only show the most recent 5 or so dates.  They can expand that date to see all the documents for that particular date.  They have to do this in each library to see everything for that one date so it's kind of clunky, but it gets the job done.  It also helps them if they don't address something for a particular meeting...they can go in and change the Meeting Date it's associated with and it'll be there at the next date.